# How to calculate the height of triangle

Tags: android

I'm trying to calculate height of triangle where user inputs length of base of triangle and the degree, I think I have the math right but it's given me back wrong answer.

What i'm trying to do is half the base to turn it into a right angle triangle and then multiplying half by tan degree, I know i'm missing something

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
            a = Double.parseDouble(input1.getText().toString());``
            b = Double.parseDouble(input2.getText().toString());
            c = (a / 2) * Math.tan(b);
            answer.setText(Double.toString(c));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I guess you consider Isosceles triangle only.
Code looks fine I think that the problem is that you give angle in degrees and you should provide radians to tan function. So just change that line to:

```
c = (a/2) * Math.tan(b*Math.PI/180);
```